# Fetch API asynchronous call returns before response

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react-redux, fetch

I have a React-Redux web application that needs to fetch data and put it into the Redux store for later use. I call the function to fetch the data but the function returns before setting the response and action is sent to store as undefined.
My work below:

```
function getFoo()
{
    return fetch(url, {
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(
            {
                "foo":{},
                "bar":{}
            }
         )
    }).then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then( function(data){
             return data
        })

}

export const fooAction=() => {

return  {
    type:'STORE_FOO',
    result:getFoo()
 };
}
```

That did not work on executing the response, it returned [object][Promise].

The same happened with this function too:

```
async function getFoo() {

    try {
        let response = await fetch(url, {
                                    headers: {
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                                    },
                                    method: 'post',
                                    body: JSON.stringify(
                                        {
                                            "foo":{},
                                            "bar":{}
                                        }
                                     ),
                                });
        let data= await response.json()
        return await data;
    } catch (e) {
        return e.message;
    }
}
```

How can I get the real response value, json object, before continuing with my action?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to handle asynchronous calls in react-redux app, you should use `redux-thunk` as a middleware.

Also, your action function should dispatch actions, instead of just returning the object.

```
export const fooAction = () => {
  return dispatch => {
   dispatch(
    type:'STORE_FOO',
    result:getFoo()
  });
 };
}
```

Comment: I am trying to get used to React and Redux, I applied my dispatch function in container .js file as: `const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return {
  onFoo: () => { dispatch(fooAction()},
 }
} `     from the tutorials I looked up. Is this a wrong implementation? (` onFoo function comes from html onSubmit action.)

Comment: http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

Just go through this article once, it will give you a basic understanding of how to create asynchronous actions.